# Different appearance for auto-connected blank values in Excel line charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a graph of data that is tracked for my work, but for various reasons it's not feasible to fill in the data for every series. I'd like the line to appear continuous in the chart, so I have 'Connect data points with line' selected in the empty cells section. No issue there.

However, I'd like the auto-filled sections of the line to appear different so that it can be seen at a glance where this has occurred (say, with a dotted rather than solid line, or with a different colour). I've tried doing this with a separate data series and secondary axes, and nothing so far has worked.

For a simple example, if we assume a simple data set with daily data like:

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | 1 |
| Jan 2 | 2 |
| Jan 3 | 4 |
| Jan 4 | 8 |
| Jan 5 | 16 |
| Jan 6 |  |
| Jan 7 |  |
| Jan 8 | 128 |
| Jan 9 | 256 |

I'd simply like the line from Jan 5 - Jan 8 that excel is auto-connecting over the blank values to look different from where there is actual data being pulled from the set.

**Note:** unlike the simple example above, my data does not follow a predictable formula that can be interpolated.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to achieve exactly this could look as follows (assuming your data is stored in the range `A1:B10`). Enter the following `IF` function in cell `C2` and copy it down accordingly: `=IF(B2="",NA(),B2)`.

Now insert a line graph and select the respective data. In this step, it is important to start with the information that includes the `#N/A` values. As a second step, add an additional line that includes the values with the empty cells (no need to have a secondary axis). Select the chart -> tab `Chart Design` -> `Select Data` -> `Hidden and Empty Cells` and select `Gaps` and `deselect Show #N/A values as an empty cell`. Then you have one line that is fully connected and one that contains gaps, which you just need to format according to your needs, e.g., same color, dashed line etc.